# Is there a hadith that forbids praising a person on their face?

Tags: source-identification

I have this hadith in my memory but I don't know the source where I heard it from, it was something along the lines of...praising someone on his face is as if you destroyed him.

Is there a hadith along these lines? Can you please mention the hadith no. if there is one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Hadeeth narrated by al Imaam Ahmad who said: 'Afaan narrated to us that Wuhayb said on the authority of Abu Bakrah:

> "A man praised another man in the presence of the Prophet - صلى الله
>   عليه و سل; he said:
>
> "Woe to you! You have cut off your companion's neck – he repeated
>   this a number of times – If it is necessary for one of you to praise
>   his companion, then say: **'I believe him to be as such, and Allah is a
>   reckoner over him, and I do not praise anyone over Allah – I believe
>   him to be like such and such.'** If one knows such about that person to
>   be true."

This Hadeeth was also collected by al Bukhaaree, Muslim, Abu Dawood, Ibn Maajah through Khaalid al Hadhaa.

Al Imaam Ahmad stated: 'Waqee' narrated to us on the authority of Hammaam ibn al Haarith who said:

> "A man approached 'Uthmaan and praised him in his presence."
>
> He [the narrator] said: "Al Miqdaad ibn al Aswad started pouring sand
>   on the praising person's face saying:
>
> **"We were ordered by the Messenger of Allaah - صلى الله عليه وسلم - to
>   pour sand over the praising people's faces when we came across them.**"

It was collected by Muslim and Abu Dawood from the Hadeeth of ath Thawree on the authority of Mansoor.

**Source:** [Praise](http://www.subulassalaam.com/articles/article.cfm?article_id=153)

Comment: There are also some others very similar to the second hadith mentioned here.

Comment: +1 I think first hadith is what I was referring to.

Comment: May I have the ref numbers to the hadees that tell us about praising people please. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found several related hadith. Here is one:

> A man praised another man in front of the Prophet. The Prophet (ﷺ)
>   said thrice, "Wailaka (Woe on you) ! You have cut the neck of your
>   brother!" The Prophet (ﷺ) added, "If it is indispensable for anyone of
>   you to praise a person, then he should say, "I think that
>   such-and-such person (is so-and-so), and Allah is the one who will
>   take his accounts (as he knows his reality) and none can sanctify
>   anybody before Allah (and that only if he knows well about that
>   person.)". - [Sahih al-Bukhari: USC-MSA web (English) reference    : Vol. 8, Book 73, Hadith 183](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/188)

You can also look [here](https://sunnah.com/search/?q=praising%20another%20man) for many additional related Hadith